# Firefox not loading website stylesheet and console showing "Source map error:request failed with status 404"

Tags: wordpress, firefox

My wordpress multisite website is not loading the stylesheet when viewed in Firefox.

The Firefox console is showing the following error:

```
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: [website]/wp-content/themes/[theme-name]/style.css?ver=5.2.2
Source Map URL: index.css.
```

I've tested the site in Chrome and Edge and this is working fine. From Firefox, I've tried opening the CSS file that the console says is returning a 404, using the URL it gives in the error message, and this is opening fine (indicating that the path seem to be correct).

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

The error says your CSS file was built using a tool that generates [source maps](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps), and Firefox failed to load the sourcemap. This doesn't prevent the stylesheet from loading and it only affects you if you use DevTools.